# Setting tree fonts on Odoo 8

Tags: python, odoo-8, odoo

Can we have more than one condition for fonts in a tree in Odoo 8?

This is my code, but it worked only for the first condition, which is `bold:parent_id==False`

```
<field name="mcu_package_line_ids" nolabel='1' widget="one2many_list" domain="[('hide','=', False)]" >
    <tree create="false" delete="false" editable="bottom" fonts="bold:parent_id==False bold:count_childs>0" default_order="sequence asc">
        <field name="display_name" />
        <field name="include" />
        <field name="name" />
        <field name="list_price" readonly="1" />
        <field name="parent_id" invisible="1" />
        <field name="hide" invisible="1" />
        <field name="count_childs" invisible="1" />
        <field name="sequence" invisible="1" />
    </tree>
</field>
```

Any idea for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `and` and `or` operators:

```
<tree create="false" delete="false" editable="bottom" fonts="bold:parent_id==False or count_childs>0" default_order="sequence asc">
    ...
</tree>
```